# Highcharts custom tooltip background SVG not calculated correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I've a custom tooltip with HTML in Highcharts, but sometimes the background SVG isn't calculated properly.

The strange thing is that it doesn't go wrong everywhere, even though it is practically the same code with different values.

I'am not able to create a fiddle with the same chart, but here is a fiddle that is showing the problem. https://jsfiddle.net/1o9s2bw8/

In the first image I hover over `2021` and in the second image I hover over `2022`
[image][image]

---

**UPDATE**
The problem occurs only on the first hover. As a workaround I've disabled all of the tooltip styles and styled the tooltip myself.

Disable tooltip styles;

```
tooltip: {
  className: 'custom-tooltip',
  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  borderWidth: 0,
  shadow: false
}
```

Custom css;

```
.custom-tooltip{
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
}
```

Comment: I think the issue is with the div's positioning - the parent `.chart-tooltip-boxplot` should be set to relative with the height defined, and the child (`.range-bar`) should be positioned as absolute https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Losh6z5v/

Comment: As a workaround I've disabled all of the default background styles (`backgroundColor: null, shadow: false, borderWidth: 0`) and styled the tooltip with css